# Seeking code highlighter recommendation for WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, codehighlighter, geshi

Can anybody recommend a reliable and decently documented code highlighter for WordPress 2.6.1? I have tried Code Snippet by Roman Roan and Developer Formatter by Gilberto Saraiva. But they don't seem to work as described in the documentation and are mangling the code snippets instead of prettifying them.

Comment: Re-opened...OP is asking about a 'code highlighter' widget...something programmers use on their blogs...seems programming related to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use [WP-Syntax](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-syntax/) and it's worked very well for me. It's supported every language I've thrown at it so far, and the colors can be customized for a particular theme (though the defaults look just fine too)

Comment: Initially, I also used this plugin. Its simplicity and the fact that it is based on a well-established library (GeSHi) are the main arguments. I noticed, however, that it does not make best use of WordPress and GeSHi, and that it was not actively developed anymore. Therefore, I started some kind of rewrite back in 2010, with good intentions in mind. It is available at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-geshi-highlight/.

Answer (score 0):

You should also checkout [syntaxhighlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/) from Google Code.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [GeSHi Syntax Highlighter Plugin](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/index.php) in [my blog](http://blog.cdleary.com) and I find it works well. Which highlighter you use tends to depend on which languages you use most frequently and how good the support is for them.

[Edit] I forgot that GeSHi is the highlighter associated with the [Wordpress SyntaxHighlighter plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/). :/

Comment: The plugin you mentioned uses the "SyntaxHighlighter JavaScript package by Alex Gorbatchev."

Answer (score 0):

WP-Syntax uses GeSHi to do the highlighting, the WordPress Syntax Highlighter uses the [Javascript SyntaxHighlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/wiki/Overview)

Answer (score 0):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-synhighlight

It utilizes shordcodes and works well in GUI editor also unlike some others (WP-Syntax has some problems with GUI).